# Suppose that for all $g\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ we have $\int f_{n}g  \to \int fg $. Prove convergence in $L^2$ problem.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

How to solve the following problem:

Let $f_n, f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for all $n \geq 1$ be such that $\|f_n\|_2 \to \|f\|_2$ as $n \to \infty$. Suppose, moreover, that $$\int f_{n}g  \to \int fg $$ for all $g \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Then $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^2$-norm.

Comment: Try using the [parallelogram law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law).

Answer (score 6):

You want to show $$ \| f - f_n \|_2 \to 0$$

Equivalently, you can show $$ \int (f-f_n)^2 d \mu = \| f - f_n \|_2^2 \to 0$$

We have $$ \| f - f_n \|_2^2  = \int (f-f_n)^2 d \mu = \int f^2 d \mu - 2 \int f f_n d \mu + \int f_n^2 d \mu$$

Since we have $\|f_n\|_2 \to \|f\|_2$, we have $\int f_n^2 d \mu \to \int f^2 d \mu$ and since we have $\int f_n g d \mu \to \int fg d \mu$ we have $\int f f_n d \mu \to \int f^2 d \mu$ so that

$$ \int f^2 d \mu - 2 \int f f_n d \mu + \int f_n^2 d \mu \to \int f^2 d \mu - 2 \int f^2 d \mu + \int f^2 d \mu = 0$$

that is, $$\| f - f_n \|_2^2 \to 0$$

and hence of course also

$$\| f - f_n \|_2 \to 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $L^2$ is a Hilbert space, you can use the parallelogram identity, as suggested in a comment. More generally, you can also use a property of any uniformly convex Banach space, which is listed as the second property [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_convex_space).
A very nice proof appears in Brezis' book on functional analysis.